# How to give multiple log-in's access to one keyword-based dataset in django app

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is the scenario I am working on: I have django app that creates records which I call sessions:

**blog.models.py**

```
class Session(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    cid = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    action_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    action_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    action_value = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    session_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

I have a dashboard page to show charts and a database page to show the records as a table:

**blog.urls.py**

```
path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='blog-home'),
path('<str:username>/dashboard/', views.dashboard and DashboardListView.as_view(), name='blog-dashboard'),
path('<str:username>/database/', views.database and SessionListView.as_view(), name='blog-database'),
```

So when you log in, my `SessionListView.as_view()` goes through the whole database and displays only those records where the Session.client == the url's 'username' value.

**Example**: when user: DummyCo logs in ([www.website.com/DummyCo/database/](http://www.website.com/DummyCo/database/)) they see only Session records where the Session.client field is 'DummyCo.' This has worked out great so far.

**But here is the problem:** I now need to provide multiple logins to users to see the same dashboard and database page.

**Example**: jim@DummyCo.com and amy@DummyCo.com both need to see the DummyCo records, but if I provided them with their own logins then their username's in the url would not match and thus the DummyCo records would not show. I thought using the built-in django Groups would be a solution but that seems to only help with authentication and permissions on the backend. I also extended my user model with a Profile model:

**users/models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    user_client = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I made the `user_client` model field to try and connect the Profile (and thus User) with the Session.client field: instead of `<str:username>/database/` I thought i'd be able to use `<str:client_user>/database/` and simply fill that field with 'DummyCo' on both Jim and Amy's profile to give them access to the records.

I read in a couple of places that the key to handling this problem is to switch the user model from one-to-one to many-to-one type early or before i build out the app. Unfortunately I have already put a ton of work into this project. I also read that I should look at the built-in User model as more of an account and less of a user. So is there a simple way to give multiple users access to one User/account?

Also, here is the views:

**blog/views.py**

```
class SessionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Session, Profile
    template_name = 'blog/database.html'
    context_object_name = 'sessions'
    ordering = ['-session_date']
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Session.objects.filter(client=user).order_by('-session_date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['distinct_campaigns'] = Session.objects.filter(client=user).values('cid').distinct().order_by('cid')
        context['distinct_action_types'] = Session.objects.filter(client=user)\
        .values('action_type')\
        .distinct().order_by('action_type')
        return context

@ login_required()
def database(request):
    context = {
    'sessions': Session.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/database.html', context, {'title': 'Database'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out a solution:

I thought I needed to do some trickery on the html file within the for loop showing my query set `sessions` but it turns out that can be adjusted in my views.py file. Before this update my views.py looked like this:

```
class SessionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Session, Profile
    template_name = 'blog/database.html'
    context_object_name = 'sessions'
    ordering = ['-session_date']
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Session.objects.filter(client=user).order_by('-session_date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['distinct_campaigns'] = Session.objects.filter(client=user).values('cid').distinct().order_by('cid')
        context['distinct_action_types'] = Session.objects.filter(client=user)\
            .values('action_type')\
            .distinct().order_by('action_type')
        return context
```

I realized the `def get_queryset(self)` was grabbing the logged-in username, then reviewing the full database and adding all records with the same session.client value as the value of the logged in user (i.e. DummyCo). So to make this work for a user like 'DummyCo_Sally', I changed the logic in that def like so:

```
class SessionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    # gets the actual user (i.e. DummyCo_Sally)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    # turns user to a string
    user_string = str(user)
    # designates the _ as the separator 
    sep = '_'
    # strips off _ and everything after it
    stripped_user = user_string.split(sep, 1)[0]
    # establishes the queryset as 'DummyCo' even though 'DummyCo_sally' is logged in
    return Session.objects.filter(client=stripped_user).order_by('-session_date')
```

I doubt this method is the best way of handling multiple users seeing one umbrella data set, but it did the trick for me. This method also likely creates a security risk for applications that have public-facing user registration. But it did the trick for me.